# How can I can a checkbox to pass through a string into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, validation, checkbox

I am working on a project right now and am having trouble figuring out something.
I have created a table in MySQL with the main input from the user being a "message" and a "creator"
What I am trying to do is have it so on the "Create message form", if a user wishes to not input their name, they can simply get a checkbox and "anonymous" would be passed through as "creator".
I havent been able to figure out how to get the "anonymous" input to get pass through.
If i type I leave the "creator" field empty and have the checkbox checked, my validations get called and says field cannot be empty, and if i remove the validations then is passes through but in the DB, the creator field is set as empty.
My next approach was to have the creator have a default of "anonymous"
in MySQL, i ran this "ALTER TABLE messages ALTER creator SET DEFAULT 'Anonymous';" and again it would call validations, and with no validations, it still enters the data as empty.
My next attempt is to maybe perhaps write an if statement in my validations, but not entirely sure how to write it out.
Hopefully this question makes sense...

UPDATE: I have since created an If statement that handles the "anonymous" checkbox. When no name is entered into the text input field, and the checkbox is checked, then "Anonymous" gets pushed into MySQL DB. NOW the issue is if I enter a name and the checkbox is unchecked, I receive a key error

> KeyError: 'creator2'

I believe it has something to do with my If statement and have had no success in fixing it...

this is my form on the user side

```
<form action="/messages/create" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="message">Enter Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="creator">From</label>
        <!-- <small class="form-text text-muted"></small> -->
        <input type="text" name="creator1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Anonymous" name="creator2" >Anonymous</input>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

this is my controller to handle the form with the bugged if statement.

```
@app.route("/messages/create", methods = ["POST"])
def create_message():
data = request.form.to_dict()
if data["creator2"]:
    data["creator"] = "Anonymous"
else:
    data["creator"] = data["creator1"]
if Message.message_validator(data):
    query_data = {
        "message": data["message"],
        "creator": data["creator"]
    }
    message_id = Message.create_message(query_data)
    return redirect("/")
return redirect("/messages/new")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I figured out why that happens, the data of a checkbox gets sent only if the checkbox is checked at the moment of the submission, that means when you submit the form without it being checked, you pass no data about that checkbox, like if it was not there at all, so when you parse the submitted form to a dictionary, you have no entry for the checkbox, thus raising the KeyError excpetion.

One fix is to check if the key is present in the dictionary.

```
@app.route("/messages/create", methods = ["POST"]) 
def create_message():
    data = request.form.to_dict()

    if "creator2" in data:
        data["creator"] = "Anonymous"
    else:
        data["creator"] = data["creator1"]

    if Message.message_validator(data):
        query_data = {
            "message": data["message"],
            "creator": data["creator"]
        }
        message_id = Message.create_message(query_data)
        return redirect("/")

    return redirect("/messages/new")
```

I'd also suggest to have a value in the checkbox and to use equal names for name and if to avoid errors

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Anonymous" name="Anonymous" value="Anonymous">Anonymous</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, as far as I know in HTML it's better to have the same value for the fields 'id' and 'name'. It can be error prone.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="anonymous" name="anonymous" >Anonymous</input>
```

Next thing I would link the anonymous checkbox with the input as it should be disabled when user declares as anonymous.

In that way, you can just use onClick methods to substitue the input value and only watch its content.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="anonymous" name="anonymous" onclick='handleClick();'>Anonymous</input>
```

In a js manner you implement the 'handleClick()' method. Something like :

```
function handleClick() {
  var chk=document.getElementById("anonymous").value;
  // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the help! If i cant get it to work, I'll give JS a shot.

Comment: @AlexMartinez did you manage to get it work ?

Comment: @MricG_FR92 yes!